# Suggestion for "plugin" static library

Tags: c++, static-libraries, static-linking

I am writing a poem's library for fun, and I have difficulties in devising my task. I have one static library, and I'd like to make a "*static plugin*" system (forgive the name).

So, I'd like to create a series of *static libraries* that respect the following rules:

- each library contains **one single object** (a class, or whatever is needed)
- the class must contain one array
- each array's item is an array of `unsigned char`

In essence, I'd like to create a series of libraries that provide, in this task, a list of poems. So, each library contains the poems of one author.

Now the part that I need is this: the library user will **just link the needed static plugin** and the main library. With this, the user may print at console the whole repository of poems, as in this simple example:

```
#include "poems.hpp"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    poems p;

    p.dump(">>> Dumping poems");

    return 0;
}
```

All the process is handled at link time

```
$ clang++ a.cpp libpoems.a libplugin_coleridge.a 
$ ./a.out
>>> Dumping poems
The Rime of the Ancient Mariner
    It is an ancient Mariner, 
    And he stoppeth one of three. 
[...]
Kubla Khan
    In Xanadu did Kubla Khan 
    A stately pleasure-dome decree: 
[...]
```

or in alternative

```
$ clang++ a.cpp libpoems.a libplugin_shelley.a 
$ ./a.out
>>> Dumping poems
Ozymandias
    O wild West Wind, thou breath of Autumn's being,
    Thou, from whose unseen presence the leaves dead 
[...]
Ode To The West Wind
    O wild West Wind, thou breath of Autumn's being,
    Thou, from whose unseen presence the leaves dead
[...]
```

I suppose I could create in `poem.hpp` some class or similar that contains calls to an external object, or something similar.

Any hints are welcome.

Comment: So you would put a function in the library that does the dump, identical name for each library and resolved by the linker. So what is the question here?

Comment: Non just a function, but also all the data needed for the dump, or for what it's worth, any other function (for instance, search for a poem).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can do this in C/C++ with only a single string in each object file.  To start with, the printing function needs to be able to process a list of poems of some sort.

I think that this sort of thing is typically done using compiler static object initializers (maybe via registration objects).

Ultimately you are going to need a symbol that the main can call which is a list of links to your strings.

So, you can create a class that is a 'add my string to a list of strings' class.  Then in each module you do a static instance of one of these adders.

As the program is loaded, the C++ runtime library will call all of the constructors of the static objects, and so your constructor should add the string to the well known list.

The order that the static objects are constructed is not defined, so make sure that the list is either a simple base type (a pointer to a linked list head) or that you do lazy construction of the list (ie that the first constructor creates the list object and assigns it to a base pointer type).

For instance:

main.cc

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "poem.h"

Poem* s_poemList = NULL;

int main() {
  Poem* poem = s_poemList;

  while (poem) {
    printf("%s\n", poem->text);
    poem = poem->next;
  }
}
```

poem.h

```
#ifndef __POEM_H__
#define __POEM_H__

class Poem;

extern Poem* s_poemList;

class Poem {
public:
  Poem(const char* text)
  : text(text) {
    next = s_poemList;
    s_poemList = this;
  }

  class Poem* next;
  const char* text;
};


#endif
```

poem1.cc

```
#include "poem.h"
static Poem poem("This is the text from Poem1\n");
```

poem2.cc

```
#include "poem.h"
static Poem poem("This is the text from Poem2\n");
```

This creates a system that will succeed if you do:

```
cc main.cc poem1.cc poem2.cc
```

Each of the objects will be linked into the executable and the linker will make sure that the constructors are called.

However, if you make the poems into an archive:

```
cc -c poem1.cc
cc -c poem2.cc
ar cr libpoems.a poem1.o poem2.o
```

and then link that library:

```
cc main.cc -lpoems
```

then it will fail to print the poems because the linker doesn't need the object files from the library so it wont link them in, so the constructors wont run so the list will remain empty.  You need to force the linker to include the objects from the library.  On my Mac I would do:

```
cc main.cc -Xlinker -force_load ./libpoems.a
```

where -Xlinker passes the following option to the linker, and -force_load tells the linker to include every object in the ./libpoems.a file even if it isn't required by main.cc